# online magzine mode

Tags: iphone

One of my customer hopes to create an online magzine which can browse and download newest contents from web.
He hope it works on ipod/iphone/ipad, but he also hope these can be migrated to android not too difficult later.
I know there is 'iWebkit' helps to create iphone web app, but I am not sure if it works for android also, or is convenient to migrate to android later.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: Are you lookin at making a native app or a web app?

Comment: It is the first time I work for creating online magzine

Comment: So I am not sure what is the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the [Adobe digital publishing platform](http://www.adobe.com/digitalpublishing/).

Comment: it is too expensive for small magazine

Comment: You need to post the parameters for what you want to do in your question. Is the magazine created from scratch for iPhone/Android or does the content exist elsewhere? How much programming work are you able/willing to do yourself? What is your budget? In what format would you provide the content? How much customisability of layout and visual design do you want? By answering these questions you'll be able to clarify your requirements and we might be able to provide more helpful answers.